# What is the url to the google-wallet production merchant center

Tags: android-pay

What is the url to the google-wallet production merchant center?

https://checkout.google.com/sell

i'm using above and takes me to the old checkout merchant center.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only integrated Checkout, that's still the best merchant center to use.  If you've integrated In-App Payments you should receive the updated digital goods merchant center.